# SNS - Get IP of Publisher?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an API Gateway endpoint that takes the bodies of requests to it and places them in an SQS queue. The API Gateway has the ability to transform the request and add requester meta, like the user agent and ip address, to the message it eventually sends to SQS.

I'd like to change this from API Gateway to SNS so that the requester would publish to an SNS topic that feeds into SQS or directly to SQS.

The issue i'm having with this is that while I can get the useragent from the requester pre-send, i can't get the ip of the user without making a call to an endpoint and having the endpoint return the ip it observed.

Is it possible for the aws SNS/SQS api to append the ip of the request to the messages they receive?

Answer (score 0):

SQS actions `SendMessage`, `SendMessageBatch` and `SetQueueAttributes` will process messages as they are received. There is no SQS/SNS configuration that could be used to modify the message. It would make sense to use SQS directly but in my opinion using SNS instead of API Gateway won't make it any better from cost/performance/implementation point of view. API Gateway appears to be your best option.